# get img src from dom.xpath

Tags: python, dom, xpath

I have this code which reads links(URLs) from a web page and prints them on the screen.

```
connection = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'):
    print link
```

It works fine. 
Now I want to do exactly same thing but in place of url's from anchor tag `a` I want to get the urls of Images which are in the HTML tag of `img` under `src`. I cant understand how this  `dom.xpath('//a/@href')` works. If someone could explain it or just guide me to a tutorial it would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an start with xpath have a look to http: [wiki/XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) or for more information to [USING XPATHS](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/xpath.xml).

`//a/@href'` selects the href attribute from all  links (`<a>` tags).

For all image src attributes this will be `//img/@src`.